# String gsub - Replace characters between two elements, but leave surrounding elements

Tags: ruby, regex

Suppose I have the following string:

> mystring = "start/abc123/end"

How can you splice out the `abc123` with something else, while leaving the "/start/" and "/end" elements intact?

I had the following to match for the pattern, but it replaces the entire string. I was hoping to just have it replace the `abc123` with `123abc`.

```
mystring.gsub(/start\/(.*)\/end/,"123abc")  #=> "123abc"
```

**Edit**: The characters between the start & end elements can be any combination of alphanumeric characters, I changed my example to reflect this.

Comment: is it always a number ?

Comment: You may just put `start` and `end` between parenthesis and reference to them in your replacement. [demo](http://regex101.com/r/jG0zT2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using this character class : `[^\/]` (all that is not a slash) and [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
mystring.gsub(/(?<=start\/)[^\/]+(?=\/end)/,"7")
```

Answer (score 3):

For your example, you could perhaps use:

```
mystring.gsub(/\/(.*?)\//,"/7/")
```

This will match the two slashes between the string you're replacing and putting them back in the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could capture the pieces of the string you want to keep and interpolate them around your replacement, this turns out to be *much* more readable than lookaheads/lookbehinds:

```
irb(main):010:0> mystring.gsub(/(start)\/.*\/(end)/, "\\1/7/\\2")
=> "start/7/end"
```

`\\1` and `\\2` here refer to the numbered captures inside of your regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're replacing the entire matched string, `"start/8/end"`, with "7". You need to include the matched characters you want to persist:

```
mystring.gsub(/start\/(.*)\/end/, "start/7/end")
```

Alternatively, just match the digits:

```
mystring.gsub(/\d+/, "7")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by grouping the start and end elements in the regular expression and then referring to these groups in in the substitution string:

```
mystring.gsub(/(?<start>start\/).*(?<end>\/end)/, "\\<start>7\\<end>")
```