# Drop values between two characters in a string

Tags: regex, r, gsub

Suppose I have multiple forms of the following string

```
x <- "/Users/name/Google Drive/Thesis/Data/Data X and Y/UK//5port/5groups.csv"
```

I want to drop the values between the first `/` and the last `/` to return only `5groups.csv`. I used `gsub` but couldn't find how to specify that pattern.

My question is the same like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116925/string-gsub-replace-characters-between-two-elements-but-leave-surrounding-ele) one but in R.

Comment: Maybe `basename(x)` ?

Comment: @zx8754 basename worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are using `sub`

```
sub('.*\\/', '', x)
#[1] "5groups.csv"
```